# Check when an SKSpriteNode passes a certain point or line

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In my game, there is an SKSpriteNode, which we will call a "gate," that is moving upwards in the scene. When the gate reaches the top of the screen, it moves back down to the bottom and begins traveling upwards again.

The way the player loses is if the character, which is located at a constant y position towards the top of the scene, collides with the gate. I have the collision and 'death' all worked out, but now I need to check if the character successfully passed 'through' the gate (meaning the gate moved past the character without hitting him). **Basically, I need to know how to check when one moving node crosses a certain y position** (in this case, that position is the character's y position). If this occurs, I want to increase the score by one.

Here is a rough sketch of the situation:
[(click here for the rough sketch)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPJu6.png)

One thing I have tried is in the update method, if the gate's y position ever equals the character's y position, I know the two nodes have crossed, so I should increase the score. It looks like this:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if gate.position.y == character.position.y {
        print("score")
        score++

    }
}
```

but doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to check when the gate crosses the character's y position?

Thanks!

Comment: This should be easy. If gate's anchor point (as well as character's anchor point) is unchanged (eg. it is 0.5, 0.5) you need to do something like this : if(character.position.y - character.size.height/2 > gate.position.y + gate.size.height/2){do your stuff}

Comment: Also note that update: method is executed many times in one second, so you should probably reposition node after the score is increased . Otherwise, the score will be increased in they way you probably don't expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What may be happening is that the y coordinates aren't the same. For example if `gate.position.y = 100`, and `character. position.y = 101`, it won't work. Try this:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

let minY = gate.position.y - 10
let maxY = gate.position.y + 10
if character.position.y > minY && character.position.y < maxY {
    print("score")
    score++

}
}
```

You can adjust the number 10 to see what works best. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I needed. Simple, but works great.